# WPF databinding not working as expected after upgrading Entity Framework from 4.4 to 6.1

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework

I have a WPF application using Prism/Unity, .Net 4 and Entity Framework 4.4.
Did a testupgrade of both .Net and EF.

.Net to 4.5.1 and EF to 6.1. With Entity Framework I also went for using DbContext instead of ObjectContext.

After some initial problems I could get the solution to build, but when testing the application some problems arose. I had different views where I use two (DevExpress) gridcontrols. One would be bound to an ObservableCollection in the ViewModel, and the other would be bound to a (child)collection in the selected item of the first gridcontrol.

After the upgrade, any objects added to the selected items "child-collection", would not get immediatly shown/reflected in the second gridcontrol.
This always worked before the upgrade, what has changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this change in behavior is that the T4-templates for DbContext do not use collections that implement INotifyCollectionChanged. A workaround for this is to modify the T4 template (in the xxModel.tt file):

- Open the xxModel.tt file
- Find and replace the two occurances of "ICollection" with "ObservableCollection". These are located approximately at lines 296 and 484
- Find and replace the first occuraece of "HashSet" with "ObservableCollection". This occurrence is located approximately at line 50. Do not replace the second occurrence of HashSet found later in the code.
- Find and replace the only occurrence of "System.Collections.Generic" with "System.Collections.ObjectModel". This is located approximately at line 424.
- Save the xxModel.tt file. This should cause the code for entities to be regenerated. If the code does not regenerate automatically, then right click on the file and choose "Run custom tool".

The above tip I found in the following article under the heading "Updating code generation for data binding": [Databinding with WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574514.aspx)

I also made a support case at DevExpress where the problem is explained even more: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T212183

Hope this will help others as well.